# If booleans are immutable in Java, how am I able to change this boolean?

Tags: boolean, immutability

The code below prints true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Boolean test = false;
        test = true;
        System.out.println(test);
```

If booleans are immutable in Java, how am I able to change test from false to true?  Shouldn't it give me an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The confusion is because of auto-boxing. The code should be *read* as

```
Boolean test = new Boolean(false);
test = new Boolean(true);
```

Thus, you are changing the **reference** test to point to a new Boolean object (with its initial value as true). The original boolean object is not being updated. In fact, there is no way to update its actual value. Thus its immutable.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  Does the original boolean of false continue to hold onto memory space then?  Is the code I wrote not good practice?

Comment: you're welcome. Yes, it continues to hold space, but its eligible for Garbage Collection, so JVM will take care of it. But its not a bad practice. What you did is perfectly fine. For such objects with limited values (eg: boolean, shortint, etc) JVM caches the values.. so that in the future if someone creates reference to say test2 = false, JVM will just point reference to this memory instead of allocating new memory. In general, always focus on code readability, let JVM take care of performance/memory.

Answer (score 1):

*If booleans are immutable in Java, how am I able to change test from false to true? Shouldn't it give me an error?*

It will not give you an error because you assign `true` to `test` variable which is a Boolean type. The output in `System.out.println()` would be `true`.

Boolean is **immutable** like Strings, you can change the value of it and allocate new mem allocation, but the first **reference** remains on the memory allocation who has the **false** value.

Answer (score 1):

"Assignability" is a completely separate concept from Immutability. Assignability is a property of fields and variables, while Immutability is a property of types.

`Boolean` (like all objects in Java) is a reference type. Essentially, it's a pointer. When we speak of immutability, it's referring to the ability of an individual object to mutate; the pointer itself can be changed to point to a different object (or to null) at any time, and that has no bearing on the Object's immutability.

An even simpler example would be

```
String greeting = "Hello, world.";
greeting = null;
```

Strings are immutable in Java, so the original String object (containing the data corresponding to the text "Hello, world.") still exists, unchanged; all we've done is made our pointer point somewhere else.

If a variable or field is declared `final`, you can no longer reassign to it, but you can still modify it if the type is mutable. That would essentially be the reverse of your situation (an immutable type with a non-final field/variable).

The difference is essentially the same as the difference between a const pointer and a pointer-to-const in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable means the value stored in the original memory location will not change.
For example

```
boolean variableOne = true;
boolean variableTwo = variableOne;
// variableOne --> true
// variableTwo --> true
```

Now if I assign false to variable two, a new memory location will be allocated to variableTwo and the value stored in variable one will not change.

```
variableTwo.invert(); //Some method that inverts the value in that memory location
// variableOne --> true
// variableTwo --> false
```

Now if booleans were mutable object, during assignment, a reference of the object would have been assigned to the new variable and changing the new variable will reflect in the original one.

This is advantageous in some places where you want to copy the value of a variable, and want the same to not change even when the original one changes.